# Javascript timing / loop issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, timing

I have this code here that's grabbing some sport statistics from a database, and updating them - and I'm trying to throw an alert (the #scorealert div) when a change is detected.  This works fine if there's just one score that has changed.  When there are multiple changes, it's displaying the wrong name - it keeps displaying the last value there, and not changing the name.

Still a beginner with javascript/ajax and learning.. please be gentle.

Thanks!

```
function getscores() {

  $.post("/get_live_scores.php", {e: <?=$entryid;?>}, function(celldata) {

    data = jQuery.parseJSON(celldata);
    $.each(data, function(i,item) {
        var pname = data[i].pname;
        var cell = data[i].key;
        var save_val = data[i].save_val;
        var wins = data[i].wins;
        var shutouts = data[i].shutouts;
        var goals = data[i].goals;
        var assists = data[i].assists;
        var ht = data[i].ht;
        var gwg = data[i].gwg;

        if ($('td#'+cell+'_goals').text() < goals) {
            $('div#scorealert').html('Goal by '+data[i].pname);
            $('div#scorealert').animate({left: '0px'});
            $('div#scorealert').delay(4000).animate({left: '-300px'});
        }
        updatecell(pname, cell, save_val, wins, shutouts, goals, assists, ht, gwg); 


    });

    updatetotal();
  });
}
```

Comment: You probably want `var data = ` (note the `var`) to keep that out of the global namespace.

Comment: Perhaps check that the results are coming in the right order? I can't see anything wrong jumping out at me...

Comment: Also, is `pname` the only field that's *not* updating?

Comment: pname i think is the only field that's not updating.. the updatecell routine is fine, it updates the correct cell in the grid.  the only dynamic data in the #scorealert div is the pname, and that's wrong.

Comment: If the line right after this line: `if ($('td#'+cell+'_goals').text() < goals) {` is the line that's not updating, it may be that the if statement is not returning true. You might want to add a `parseInt(...text())` too.

Comment: this is the post data coming in.. edited to just show 2 records of ones that should update:
`
    [{"pname":"Tomas Vokoun","key":"lnhlcom-p323","save_val":2.3,"wins":5,"shutouts":0,"goals":4,"assists":0,"ht":0,"gwg":0},{"pname":"Dwayne Roloson","key":"lnhlcom-p856","save_val":3.8,"wins":0,"shutouts":0,"goals":4,"assists":0,"ht":0,"gwg":0}]
`

so i'm manually setting the goals # in the DB so it updates those 2 values.. name field is right, but it kicks back 'Dwayne Roloson' for both #scorealerts.

Comment: Add your code to the question as an edit, not in a comment.

Comment: dang it.  having problems figuring out how to format the inline code.  it must be returning true though, as the scorealert div shows up twice.  it pops in, retracts, pops in (with the same, incorrect name), and retracts again.

Answer (score 1):

I'll be honest; I can't see why it's only displaying the first. As far as I can tell, it should be displaying the last. Reason being: in the each loop, you are calling `.html()` on the div, which will replace that alert div's contents with the new contents. Unless the `.delay()` function interrupts the timing of that, too?

I would add your goal-scorers (etc) to the div with .append() or another non-destructive DOM-addition function, and then call the animation (full of all scorers) after the loop has finished.

[edited to add results of comment discussion:]

Since .append() adds them all to the same div (which was not the desired effect), the way to keep them in distinct alert containers is to create those containers dynamically as they are needed.

Comment: If it was doing that, it should show the last in the list, not the first, although the OP could be wrong about that.

Comment: sorry, you are correct.  it actually is displaying the last value twice.  i've updated my initial post.  :(

my intent though was to have the box actually slide in/out for each new score alert, not display them all at once.

Comment: the .append method works and gets the proper names in there, though i'd prefer to slide a message out for each individual score update.  if anyone has an idea of what's wrong with my code where i was originally intending to do that, that'd be great.

for now, i got the .append going, which is a good step at least.  thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you wanted it that way. You can create new "scoreAlert" divs dynamically and then execute your animations on those, instead of staying married to the one scoreAlert div.

Answer (score 0):

Please check `e: <?=$entryid;?>`

Is it generated from php ? if that is true, it won't change after php generated it and send it to the browser. so your javascript will always get the same value and always posting the same data.

Comment: there's some header data at the top to handle this:

`
    <?
    Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
    $entryid = intval($_GET['entryid']);
`
etc...

Comment: do you have a lot of div with class scorealert ? how to do make sure for each scorealert, only that div is updated. is it updated multiple time so you only get the last "Goal by" ? Please use firebug to trace it...

Comment: Please check if "var pname" changes during the loop, if it changes, the problem is $('div#scorealert').html('Goal by '+data[i].pname);, you just keep updating it in the loop...

Comment: Confirmed with alert that the pname value is certainly changing.

Comment: can you check with this code? $('div#scorealert').append('Goal by '+data[i].pname+'<br/>');

Comment: Just did - two different names, slides in twice.

Comment: very easy, you construct the "display string" inside the loop and do html, anime delay outside the loop!